# Java-Node clarity

Tags: java, nodes

I am trying to add a Node to the End of a list and this is what I came up with. I'm just wondering if I set tail=head if that's the same thing as tail=add? Or if I have tail=head.next if that's the same as tail=add?
Thanks in advance

```
public BasicLinkedList<T> addToEnd(T data) {
    Node add= new Node(data);
    Node curr=head;
    if(size==0){
        head= add;
        tail=head;  //is it okay to make this= head? Or should it be =add?
    }else if(size==1){
        head.next=add;
        tail=head.next;  //is it okay to make this= head.next? Or should it be =add?
    }else{
        while(head.next!= null){
            curr=head.next;
        }curr.next = add;
        tail = add;
    }
    size++;
    return this; 

}
```

Comment: I believe you may have a logic issue. `while(head.next!= null){`, that should be checking `curr.next` otherwise you'll find yourself in an infinite loop as head isn't changing in the loop so its always going to be true.

Comment: Hint: You don't need the `if(size == 1)` block.

Answer (score 2):

For the answer to

```
//is it okay to make this= head? Or should it be =add?
```

Yes either is fine, `head` an `add` are are references to the same object.

and

```
//is it okay to make this= head.next? Or should it be =add?
```

Again, either is fine here also, as `head.next` and `add` are references to the same object.